# How to call parameterised variable from other method into another of the same class?

Tags: java, variables, methods

This project is quite necessary for me to complete..So please someone help me doi ng it..i have been trying the to solve the below mentioned problem since 20 days....This is my code having two methods, how do I call variables from variables() into another method? I need to use variables in variables() into another functions.

Below is the variable method:

```
 public void variables(String mm,String Maths,String computer,String english,String hindi,String arts,String physics,String chemistry,String biology,int mmi,int mmf,int Math,
            int com,int hin,int eng,int art,int chem,int bio,int phy,int sum,float fin){
              mm = Marks.getText();
            mmi = Integer.parseInt(mm);
           mmf = mmi*8;

           Maths = jTextField2.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           computer= jTextField6.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           english = jTextField8.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           hindi = jTextField7.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           arts = jTextField9.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           physics = jTextField3.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           chemistry = jTextField4.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
          biology = jTextField5.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           Math = Integer.parseInt(Maths);
          com = Integer.parseInt(computer);
        hin = Integer.parseInt(hindi);
         eng = Integer.parseInt(english);
         art = Integer.parseInt(arts);
         chem = Integer.parseInt(chemistry);
         phy = Integer.parseInt(physics);
         bio = Integer.parseInt(biology);

         sum = Math+com+hin+eng+art+chem+phy+bio;     
         fin = (sum*100)/mmf;


            }
```

And this is another method:

```
   //I want to call the variables of the Variables() method to this one..but how?? 
    public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 


         float flin = Third.variables(fin);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Percentage for this Cycle Test is: "+flin+"%");
          this.dispose();
          Fourth  IV = new Fourth();
          IV.setVisible(true);



         }
```

Comment: It's extremely difficult to tell what you're actually asking. Maybe you want an array? And this is a volunteer help site; if you want "urgent" help, you can hire me at my usual rate with a 2-hour minimum.

Comment: @chrylis I think you should also tell him your usual rate ,for he being new to stack overflow.

Comment: @HimanshuMittal first of all you need to improve your question code blocks so that it may be easily readable

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @HimanshuMittal i think you need to use global variables so that they may be available for use in other methods as and when required.

Comment: @javafan: some tips: (1) it's better to help and then do something else, don't wait around for replies. It is quite common for people to respond to comments several days later; (2) my experience of people who beg for urgency is that they are often just looking for free labour, and so are likely to abandon their questions anyway when they see downvotes; (3) I think it is quite risky to make a major effort in an answer in such a case, since your work may be taken and you might not be rewarded by the OP for it.

Comment: @halfer Sir you are experienced and i will remember your tips. Thanks.

Comment: @javafan i am extremely sorry fr using using  "urgent" and nt responding quickly

Comment: i am new to this website but not to java

Comment: actually i want to call variable - float fin in the second method..now how do i do that

Comment: it gives an error that variable not found..

Comment: @javafan look m srry for replying late (only few minutes)..now pls help me.. i am in serious trouble..this is my boards project..and this is the only part where i got stuck..so pls..

Comment: *so pls refrain from mocking at me in such a away..(Btw i wasnt looking for free labour but u considered urself one of them..its not my fault..)*  - After you add comment like this, I think no one will help you. So please dont discourage stackoverflow users.

Comment: @blasanka did u read wht he commented

Comment: i was hardly a few minutes late and he doubted me and simply mocked at me.

Comment: someone pls give the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables as i said int the comment.

For example:-

```
class Print
{
static int a;// i will use this variable in different functions

void set(int x)
{
a=x;    // a is used here
}

void display()
{
System.out.print(a);// a is printed(used) here 

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
Print obj=new Print();
obj.set(5);
obj.display();

}


}
```

Similarly you could declare as many global variables and use them in different functions as you want.I hope it helps you and Good luck(sorry for mocking).

Comment: ty so much..but cud u pls give the example using my code..pls

Answer (score 0):

Ok Himanshu here i tried to give example using your code.

```
class Example
{
static float fin=0.0f;// global variable declared and initialised with default value

public void variables(String mm,String Maths,String computer,String english,String hindi,String arts,String physics,String chemistry,String biology,int mmi,int mmf,int Math,int com,int hin,int eng,int art,int chem,int bio,int phy,int sum,float fin)
{
              mm = Marks.getText();
            mmi = Integer.parseInt(mm);
           mmf = mmi*8;

           Maths = jTextField2.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           computer= jTextField6.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           english = jTextField8.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           hindi = jTextField7.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           arts = jTextField9.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           physics = jTextField3.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           chemistry = jTextField4.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
          biology = jTextField5.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
           Math = Integer.parseInt(Maths);
          com = Integer.parseInt(computer);
        hin = Integer.parseInt(hindi);
         eng = Integer.parseInt(english);
         art = Integer.parseInt(arts);
         chem = Integer.parseInt(chemistry);
         phy = Integer.parseInt(physics);
         bio = Integer.parseInt(biology);

         sum = Math+com+hin+eng+art+chem+phy+bio;     
         fin = (sum*100)/mmf;


        }

// Use fin here because it is declared globally(after class before function) 
public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 


         float flin = fin;  // Used fin directly as it is global
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Percentage for this Cycle Test is: "+flin+"%");
          this.dispose();
          Fourth  IV = new Fourth();
          IV.setVisible(true);



         }

}
```

Comment: i mean the value of fin in teh second method..will it be updated/

Comment: and m using the method in other class

Comment: i wrote float flin = fIII.variables(fin);

Comment: fIII is the object of the class

Comment: its says variable not found